# hibernate two way mapping insert and delete beginner

Tags: java, hibernate

Today I did some experiments with hibernate. Unfortunately it seems if I’m misunderstanding something about the sessions. 
I have three entities (book “buch”, user “benutzer” and rent “leihstellung”). 
Each book knows about the rents, it’s concerned by. Each rent knows about the associated book. Furthermore each rent knows about the fitting user and of course each user knows the associated rents.

I explicitly want to have this two way mappings.

Now I wrote a small tester which inserts some data. The insert progress works as expected. After inserting some data I would like to delete a user. 
If I do this before the commit, hibernate gives me an error, because the user will be reinserted be the rents it belongs to (that even happens, if I manually delete the user from this rents). Here I don’t really understand why that happens.

Everything works fine, if I do a session.close and open a new session for deleting the user.

I guess, that there is a smarter way to do this within one session. But unfortunately I don’t know how this can be done. 
Any explanation is welcome.

```
public class Worker implements Iworker{

    private Sessiongetter sg;

    private MainMenu mm;

    public void work(File datei)
    {
        sg = new Sessiongetter();
        Session session = sg.getSesseion();
        WlBuchart wlBuchart = new WlBuchart(1, "Sachbuch");

        Buch buch = new Buch("test", "ich", 1);
        buch.setWlBuchart(wlBuchart);
        Buch buch2 = new Buch("versuch", "du",2);
        buch2.setWlBuchart(wlBuchart);
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(wlBuchart);
        session.save(buch);
          session.save(buch2);

        Benutzer benutzer = new Benutzer("hans", "dampf", "Lehrer", "versuch");
        session.save(benutzer);

        Leihstellung leihstellung = new Leihstellung(benutzer, buch);
        Leihstellung leihstellung2 = new Leihstellung(benutzer, buch2);
        session.save(leihstellung);
        session.save(leihstellung2);

        benutzer.addLeihstellung(leihstellung);
        benutzer.addLeihstellung(leihstellung2);
        session.update(benutzer);

        buch.addLeihstellung(leihstellung);
        buch2.addLeihstellung(leihstellung2);
        session.update(buch);
        session.update(buch2);
        session.remove(benutzer);

        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();


        session.close();


        System.out.println("fertig");
    }

package code.logik;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.Session;

@Entity
@Table(name="benutzer")
public class Benutzer {

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String vorname, nachname, gruppe; 
    @Id
    private String kennung;
    private boolean admin;
    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String kennwort;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="benutzer")
    private List<Leihstellung>leihstellungs;


    public String getKennwort() {
        return kennwort;
    }

    public void setKennwort(String kennwort) {
        this.kennwort = kennwort;
    }

    public Benutzer(String vorname, String nachname, String gruppe, String kennung) {
        this.vorname=vorname; 
        this.nachname=nachname; 
        this.gruppe=gruppe; 
        this.kennung=kennung;
        this.leihstellungs= new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public Benutzer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public String getGruppe() {
        return gruppe;
    }

    public String getKennung() {
        return kennung;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public List<Leihstellung> getLeihstellungs() {
        return leihstellungs;
    }

    public void addLeihstellung(Leihstellung leihstellung)
    {
        leihstellungs.add(leihstellung);
    }



    public int compare(Benutzer other)
    {
        if (this.getNachname().compareTo(other.getNachname())!=0)
        {
            return this.getNachname().compareTo(other.getNachname());
        }
        return this.getVorname().compareTo(other.getVorname());
    }


}

package code.logik;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.ManyToAny;

@Entity
@Table(name="buch")
public class Buch {

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String titel;
    private String autor;

    @ManyToOne
    private WlBuchart wlBuchart;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="buch")
    private List<Leihstellung>leihstellungs;

    public WlBuchart getWlBuchart() {
        return wlBuchart;
    }

    public void setWlBuchart(WlBuchart wlBuchart) {
        this.wlBuchart = wlBuchart;
    }

    @Id
    private int nummer;



    public Buch(String titel, String autor,int nummer) {
        this.titel=titel; 
        this.autor=autor; 
        this.nummer=nummer;
        leihstellungs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Buch() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public String getTitel() {
        return titel;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }



    public int getNummer() {
        return nummer;
    }

    public List<Leihstellung> getLeihstellungs() {
        return leihstellungs;
    }

    public void addLeihstellung(Leihstellung leihstellung)
    {
        leihstellungs.add(leihstellung);
    }


}


package code.logik;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="leihstellung")
public class Leihstellung {

    @ManyToOne
    private Benutzer benutzer; 

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private LocalDate von;

    private LocalDate bis;

    @ManyToOne
    private Buch buch;

    public Leihstellung(Benutzer benutzer, Buch buch) {
        this.benutzer=benutzer; 
        this.buch=buch; 
        this.von = LocalDate.now();
    }

    public Leihstellung() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setAbgegeben()
    {
        bis = LocalDate.now();
    }

    public Benutzer getBenutzer() {
        return benutzer;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LocalDate getVon() {
        return von;
    }

    public LocalDate getBis() {
        return bis;
    }

    public Buch getBuch() {
        return buch;
    }



}
```

Comment: It seems you posted the code that works fine, instead of posting the code that doesn't.

Comment: sorry, just updated this

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. I had to delete the references from the connected rents and books. 
Now everything works find.